Should ILockBytes::SetSize preserve existing data?
I have read the MSDN documentation about ILockBytes::SetSize(), but it does not answer precisely whether my implementation of SetSize() should preserve existing data.
For example, if the current buffer size is 100, and SetSize(120) is called, should it preserve data in the first 100 bytes in the resized buffer?
Also, if the current buffer size is 100, and SetSize(70) is called, should it preserve data in the first 70 bytes in the resized buffer?
In other words - should I call realloc() or single alloc() in C++?

IMO it's pretty clear: If the cb parameter is larger than the current byte array, the byte array is extended to the indicated size by filling the intervening space with bytes of undefined value and If the cb parameter is smaller than the current byte array, the byte array is truncated to the indicated size. "Extended" and "truncated" are not "replaced".

Side note: in C++, neither malloc() nor realloc() should ever be used. Even new and delete are for very rare cases. Generally, use std::vector instead, it manages memory allocations / deallocations automatically. Also, it already has the resize() member function,  which does preserve the contents.

@heapunderrun std:;vector is orthogonal here, different API space. malloc\calloc in Microsoft's implementation, or rather Windows API heap functions are more relevant, but COM+ API already takes care of that.

@Swift-FridayPie If you are implementing this, use a std vector with a custom allocator as your 2nd pass in the implementation (1st pass being default alllocator, just to get some of your unit tests up).  There are things a std vector with custom allocator can't do: for everything else, there's mastercard.

well, if that's an array ILockBytes. It can be anything, a file, shared memory, etc. Therefore the question is quite naive.

Yes, the existing byte values are expected to be preserved.  Extending the size of the array just adds new bytes of unspecified value to the end of the array.  And reducing the size of the array just chops off the trailing bytes from the end of the array.
If extending the array did not preserve existing data, then writing new bytes to the end of the array via ILockBytes::WriteAt() would be meaningless:

If ulOffset is past the end of the byte array and cb is greater than zero, ILockBytes::WriteAt increases the size of the byte array. The fill bytes written to the byte array are not initialized to any particular value.

How you decide to implement the expansion/reduction logic internally is up to you.

Remy, thank you very much!

May be it is possible to answer in this question: ILockBytes must support LockRegion and UnlockRegion methods. I can guarantee, that my program which implements ILockBytes for StgCreateDocfileOnILockBytes, will not read/write ILockbytes's memory in parallel (concurrently) itself. Should I implement Lock/Unlock ? In other words - can another program (OS) try to access this memory concurrently ?

@LUN that is a completely different question that should be posted separately.
